# Redirect python script output to grep

Tags: python, c++, shell, grep, cocos2d-x

There is a python script that builds **cocos2dx-project**. When it runs it prints out all the warning and error messages. But I want to get only those lines that contain "error". Therefore, I do the following:

```
python ./build_native.py | grep "error"
```

But it still prints everything, not only "error" lines.

EDIT:

In case you need the content of the script file, you can see it [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/templates/cpp-template-default/proj.android/build_native.py).

Comment: The above works perfectly fine for a script I just wrote that alternates printing `"hello"` and `"error"` 20 times. Mind giving us a sample of the output of build_native.py?

Comment: See my edit please. Actually it is not the direct output of the script but the compiler that script invokes. Does this change something the way pipe works?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`. Only then will grep filter out all lines not containing "error"

```
python ./build_native.py 2>&1 | grep "error"
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I forget? That's how bad to program in windows. :(

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this, if you just want to pipe error:

```
python ./build_native.py 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep "error"
```

Comment: This will hide `stdout` messages.

Comment: Don't you want this? My assumption was that OP do not want to include error in stdout, only error in traceback.

Comment: I don't presume to know what the OP wants.